# Google Maps API for iOS Report a bug

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I check if a user tabs the button "Report a problem" in the iOS StreetView SDK from Google (the one on the lower right corner)?

I know I'm not allowed to remove the Google logo, but is it possible to remove the "report a problem" view? And if not, how can I detect if a user presses on it? (it opens safari with a url to google with the location information (which is exactly the issue, because the location needs to be secret))

Thanks in advance!

[image]